# Как запустить android приложение с определенными JVM флагами?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Вот такая ситуация: падает приложение с ошибкой `outOfMemoryError`. Хочу отловить это событие и хочу, чтобы когда это случилось, `JVM` создал `HPROF` файл. Как запустить приложение на устройстве с определенными `JVM` флагами? Обычно это делалось просто `-XX:HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`. Или может есть какие-то встроенные удобные тулзы в Android Studio? Потому что я хочу запихнуть этот `HPROF` файл в `MemoryAnalyzer`. Но, может, этот метод уже устарел?

Comment: Я знаю что в манифесте можно расширить кучу. До какого размера правда точно неизвестно. это зависит от производителя телефона. Пропиши в манифесте  это:  android:largeHeap="true" 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap

Comment: @argamidon не, проблем с разом кучи нет:) Нужно просто, чтобы она в определенный момент сама создалась просто. Для более точного анализа проблемы.

Comment: Я не использовал Android Studio, я использовал Эклипс. В нём  была кнопка DDMS (Dalvik Debug Monitor Server) - тулза которая умеет анализировать кучу... (точно не увере, давно это было. ). Может быть она уже устаревшая - далвик сдох ведь, незнаю. По-моему она должна идти с Андроид SDK, так что поищите в папках. А вообще, у меня тоже падала моя Андроид прога с такой же ошибкой. Я примерно знал место возникновения - создавалась большая картинка 2k * 2k пикселей. Я это дело ловил и обрабатывал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` это флаг Oracle VM, в Dalvik и ART его нет.

В общем нужно или вручную создавать HPROF или если скажем проблема у заказчика - натыкать запись в лог состояние памяти по всему коду.

Ну и перехватывать OOMe тоже можно, только ловить не Exception a Error, в try-cach или глобально.

См. также видео с Google IO на эту тему - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: Ну, жаль, что так нельзя. Чтож, спасибо за ответ:) Буду значит ручками записывать эти HPROF'ы